# Moodle API - get all completions per course

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I have an external app that needs to know which users have completed a course in Moodle via the API.  That is to say, it will want to know who completed course 123, and be given back a list.  So far, the only way I've found to do this is "core_enrol_get_enrolled_users" to get the enrolled users, then iterating over that and hitting "core_completion_get_course_completion_status" for each enrolled user.  Performance is obviously terrible as you end up with a round trip per user.

Is there any way I can get Moodle to give me all the completions for a course in just one request?

Comment: through database you can get the courses list which is completed

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way is to implement said web service by yourself, since the five completion-related functions currently implemented do not suffice your request.

[image]